# How to select from List of KeyValuePair?

Tags: c#, generic-list

I have a list of KeyValuePair (Key is string type and value is int type). And I want to return the key value pair list which will get my matching criteria
                     example : return a list where Key = "A" and Value = 10.

How select will work on this and how to write the expression to get my required result ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a LINQ expression like so:

```
IList<KeyValuePair<string, int>> values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
```

add your key values.

```
IList<KeyValuePair<string, int>> result = values.Where(v => v.Key == "A" && v.Value == 10).ToList();
```

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using the KeyValuePair list, you can use the

```
Dictionary <string, int> dictionary = new Dictionary <string, int> ().
```

To search our collection we will use the **First** operator and even better would be if we use the operator **FirstOrDefault**. Why? Description below. Searching through the operator is much faster because the collection is searched element by element to the first encountered item that satisfies the condition. While, the operator **Where** searches the entire collection.

Now we are adding a new entries to the dictionary, key must be unique (they can not be two entries with the same key).

For example, let's add some entries to the collection.

```
dictionary.Add ("one", 1);
dictionary.Add ("two", 2);
dictionary.Add ("three", 3);
```

Now, using LINQ can in a very easy and fast way to get the item that interests us. Then we can look for the key element because we know that this is unique.
There are two ways:

The first way guarantees that we will not be returned exception in the absence of the element search (eg. Key = "four"). The result will be an empty key and a value of 0.

```
KeyValuePair <string, int> results = dictionary.FirstOrDefault (v => v.Key.Equals ("two"));
```

The second way may generate an error when the element search is not in the collection.

```
KeyValuePair <string, int> results = dictionary.First (v => v.Key.Equals ("two"));
```

Now you can retrieve the values:

```
string key = results.Key;
int value = results.Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var list = kvList.Where(kv => kv.Key == "A" && kv.Value == 10).ToList();
```